# Inserting a text where cursor is in the LWC lightning-textarea

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a requirement in my application, When user clicks on a link/button, we want timestamp/user name to be inserted where the cursor is, or appended to the textarea which has the focus.

For example, if the cursor/focus is on a textarea saying 'Welcome to Salesforce ' and when user clicks on a link/button, then i want the textarea text to be modified to, 'Welcome to Salesforce 02/06/2020 - sflearner'.

I know how to implement this in regular .net applications using javascript/jquery.

Can I achieve this in Salesforce LWC without third party tool?

Comment: You should take a look LWC documentation (https://recipes.lwc.dev/#parent for exemple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest I'm willing to get for you:

### JavaScript

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';

export default class testLwc extends LightningElement {
    @track textValue = 'Hello World';
    @track Name;

    handleClick() {
        this.textValue += ' ' + this.Name + ' ' + Date.now().toLocaleString();
    }

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: USER_ID, fields:[NAME_FIELD]}) 
    wireuser ({error,data}) {
        if(data) {
            this.Name = data.fields.Name.value;
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

### HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-textarea 
        name="input1" 
        label="Enter some text" 
        value={textValue}
    ></lightning-textarea>
    <a href="#" onclick={handleClick}> click me</a>
</template>
```

### Output:

[image: Output]

### Notes

In terms of making sure that it goes to the text area that has focus, you'll want to create an onfocus event handler that can record in JS which area has focus. one of the things I try to avoid doing is referencing the dom whenever possible so I would probably do this by creating an Id to value map of all of your text areas in the JS. Then your ON focus can store the Id and your handle click can use the ID to reference the string that needs to be updated.

### Cursor Positioning in Text Area

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745998/837985) has a native JS solution to getting the cursor position that might help you. In order to do this will you need to be able to traverse the DOM.

[Here is one supported way to work with the shadow dom.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work)

### References

1. [LWC Component reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components)
2. [LWC Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc)
3. [JavaScript Date Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Thanks gNerb. I agree to avoid referencing the dom. The solution you had provided always appends the timestamp at the end. I didn't give the right example about focus. Is there a way to insert the timestamp where the user cursor is. If user put their cursor next to the word Welcome, can we insert the text like this.  'Welcome 02/06/2020 - sflearner to Salesforce'

Comment: @sflearner I would say, don't do that? I can't imagine any good reason for it. BUT if you need to, I updated my answer with a little more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it:

```
const textArea = this.template.querySelector('lightning-textarea');
textArea.setRangeText(Date.now().toLocaleString());
this.textValue = textArea.value;
```